# Robot Framework: Iast argument shows invalid syntax in test step

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am trying to write test steps that adds an item by providing values via arguments. But for the last argument, it shows **invalid argument syntax** error

These are the **test steps**:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Configure proxy
    Add umbrellafields  https://nightly.ping.io:1003  8Uq3GR9mHiTrazXBlEnNyGAfCNlPXULakC6s17ka2  mtAJGYElUO6e7bst9Ng6371fXhDRPBKr7oQyQCWVj  http://nightly.ping.io:13001
```

These are the keywords:

```
***Keywords***
Add umbrellafields
    [Arguments]     ${url}  ${apikey}   ${authtoken}    {elasticsearch}
    Input Text  name=apiUmbrella.url  ${url}
    Input Text  name=apiUmbrella.apiKey  ${apikey}
    Input Text  name=apiUmbrella.authToken  ${authtoken}
    Input Text  name=apiUmbrella.elasticsearch  ${elasticsearch}
    Click Element   id=proxy-save
    confirm Page Contains Remove
```

When run the script, it somehow is unable to use the 4th argument to input the given value in the related field.
I used name attribute instead of id because the ids are dynamically changed for the input field element.

It gives the following error message in the log:
[error message for last argument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQYeT.png)

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.
Some helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't link to a picture of an error. Instead, include the error in the body of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing the `$` on the elasticsearch argument:

Instead of this:

```
[Arguments]     ${url}  ${apikey}   ${authtoken}    {elasticsearch}
```

... you need this:

```
[Arguments]     ${url}  ${apikey}   ${authtoken}    ${elasticsearch}
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot! I totally missed out that syntax! Much appreciated!